# How to never lose connectivity to Tor after hibernating the computer?

Tags: help, censorship

I am in an university that allows students to access internet only during 5pm to 2am. But the great thing is that if you use Tor and do not disconnect, you will still have internet connectivity after 2am for as long as your Tor remain connected. So, what I do is that I connect to Tor at night when the internet is working and keep my laptop on all night just to keep my internet working for the morning.

Now I am looking for a better ways to do this in which I don't have to keep my laptop on for the whole night just to make sure I don't lose Tor connectivity. I thought about hibernating my computer keeping Tor connected and expected to be connected to Tor in the morning but that didn't worked. But I observed that this trick works for short period of time say 3,5 minutes. Keeping it hibernated for long, it loses Tor connectivity and I am left with no internet in the morning.

I am desperately looking for a solution to this problem. I need internet to be productive. I am a computer science student but believe it or not the university administration doesn't provide internet all the time because of complaints from other student's parents.

Anyway, that's another story. So, if anyone could help me with this issue I would be very grateful. All I want is some way through which I can keep my Tor connection maintained even after powering off my machine so after I switch it on after long time I still have the connection to Tor established.

Technical Details:
In order for me to connect to the internet I have to configure my browser to use the HTTPS proxy on 172.16.12.2:3128. The internet doesn't works otherwise. The same goes for Tor. In order to connect to Tor I need to configure it to use it with these proxy settings, otherwise it doesn't works.

Please help! I have come a long way for this.

Comment: Consider using a VPN as you don't need to anonymize your surfing behavior. You will also have higher transmission rates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I am looking for a better ways to do this in which I don't have to keep my laptop on for the whole night just to make sure I don't lose Tor connectivity. I thought about hibernating my computer keeping Tor connected and expected to be connected to Tor in the morning but that didn't worked.

On hibernation, the contents of your volatile storage (RAM) is written to non-volatile storage (the harddisk/ssd) and the computer is fully powered off.  This means that the open TCP/IP connection to the Tor network (or any network for that matter) will eventually time out.

This isn't really specific to Tor, since expecting connections to persist when a computer is off for extended periods of time isn't really realistic.

> All I want is some way through which I can keep my Tor connection maintained even after powering off my machine so after I switch it on after long time I still have the connection to Tor established.

No such thing exists.  You could consider using a low powered single board computer (Eg: A [BeagleBone Black](http://beagleboard.org/black)) as an anonymizing router, and leaving that on, but the fact that you will still have a computer on does not change.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Sir. So, now I guess I need to find other way to do get internet access. Here's another idea that I have. During the time internet access is denied, the university proxy server doesn't block my access to internet if I am connected to Tor but it blocks my requests for a new connection to Tor. Isn't there any way through which I can pass the request to connect to Tor in the same way I am able to use internet when I am connected with Tor?

Comment: @user3544994 No; like the answer says, this has nothing to do with Tor really... the router is just blocking new connection attempts, but is not killing existing connections.

Answer (score 1):

Use Raspberry Pi 2 =) It will eat almost no electricity, but will hold Tor up 24/7/365 for you. And you will connect to it as a router, or even as a WiFi hotspot anytime you need it